# Is there any reason behind Todo Aoi and Iori Utahime having similar facial scars?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

The third-year student Todo Aoi from Kyoto Jujutsu Tech School has a prominent facial scar on the left side of his face, running vertically over his eye (though it doesn't seem to impair his vision in any way).

> [image: Screenshot from episode 14 showing a close-up of Todo Aoi's face, with his facial scar visible.]

The semi-first grade jujutsu sorcerer from the same school, Iori Utahime, who is leading that school's contingent for the Tokyo-Kyoto Sister School Goodwill Event, also has a similar scar running horizontally across the right side of her face.

> [image: Screenshot from episode 14 showing a close-up of Iori Utahime's face, with her facial scar visible.]

Is there any reason behind these two characters have these similar scars? Did they perhaps receive this scar under the same (or similar) circumstances?

Alternatively, is it possible that these are not actually scars, but birthmarks of some sort, in which case I would ask whether there is any connection between these two characters other than teacher and student?